# std::enable_if_t and std::array implementation

Tags: c++

How can I use this function? (syntax)

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_array_v<T>>>
void foo(T&& a)
{
  std::cout << a.size() << std::endl;
}
```

because this is error

```
std::array<std::string, 3> arr { "1", "2", "3" };
foo<std::array<std::string, 3>>(arr);
```

this error too

```
std::array<std::string, 3> arr { "1", "2", "3" };
foo<>(arr);
```

this error too

```
std::array<std::string, 3> arr { "1", "2", "3" };
foo<std::array<std::string, 3>, 3>(arr);
```

link: https://godbolt.org/z/ToMeGe5d5

**PS:**
How to use exactly this function? How exactly can it be used, at least with C-style arrays?

This example is taken from the book C++ Templates. David Vandevoord and more...

Where it says that the first way is:

```
template<typename T, size_t N> 
void foo(const T(&a)[N])
```

And the second one, just this one:

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_array_v<T>>> 
void foo(T&& a)
```

Comment: Removed the `c++-concepts` tag which is specifically for C++20 concepts, which are not being used here.

Comment: You can use the [std::is_same_v](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) to check for a specific type. Note that std::array is not a std type, it's a class template, so you need a templated is_same.

Comment: `std::is_array_v` is to detect C-arrays, not `std::array` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_array IMO this is overkill, `tempalte<typename T, size_t N> void foo(T (&a)[N])` is better and more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That function is (almost<sup>[1]</sup>) uncallable as written:

- `std::is_array_v` is only `true` for built-in C-style arrays.  That is `std::is_array_v<int[10]>` is `true`, but `std::is_array_v<std::array<int, 10>>` is `false`.
- Built-in C-style arrays do not have a `size` member function.

That means that for any parameter type that will satisfy your type constraint, the body of the function will fail to compile.

---

You don't really need a type constraint though.  You can just make your parameter a `std::array`:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void foo(const std::array<T, N>& a)
{
  std::cout << a.size() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 4> arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    foo(arr); // prints 4
}
```

Or if you're trying to get the size of a built-in C-style array:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void foo(const T(&a)[N])
{
  std::cout << N << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  foo(arr); // prints 4
}
```

---

Since you seem dead-set on using this overly-complex (and somewhat incorrect) `enable_if_t`-based type check, you could re-write the body to work with built-in C-style arrays by doing something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_array_t<T>>>
void foo(T&& a)
{
  std::cout << std::size(a) << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  foo(std::move(arr));
}
```

Note the seemingly unnecessary `std::move`.  Your type constraint has yet another problem in that `std::is_array_t<int(&)[]>` is `false`.  This causes the function to become invalid when the forwarding reference parameter deduces `T` to be a reference type, as is the case when the function is passed an lvalue.  To avoid that problem, you can change the type constraint to check `std::is_array_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>`, but if you're changing the signature at all you would be better off using the simpler version that simply accepts a `T(&)[N]` and deduces `N`.

Note also that the `T(&)[N]` overload of `std::size` was introduced in C++17.  If using an older version of the language, you can implement your own array size function template as

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t size(T(&)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

---

[1]:  Technically `foo<std::array<std::string, 3>&, void>(arr)` works, but that's just because you've implemented the type check in such a way that it can be worked around by supplying something in place of the default template argument.

Comment: OK, but how to use exactly this function? How exactly can it be used, at least with C-style arrays? It doesn't work with any arrays.
This example is taken from the book C++ Templates. David Vandevoord and more...
Where it says that the first way is:

`template<typename T, size_t N>
void foo(const T(&a)[N])`

And the second one, just this one:

`template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_array_v<T>>>
void foo(T&& a)`

Comment: @chatlanin Like I said; it is essentially unusable as-is.  The only workaround is given in my footnote.  I added a section on how you could change the body of the function to work with the given signature.  The signature is not ideal though, since its type check can be defeated, as I did in my footnote.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just saw this implementation in the mentioned book. And I realized that I didn't know something.:)

Answer (score 6):

The function is constrained so that it accepts only *built-in* arrays as argument, not `std::array`. `std::is_array_v` tests only for built-in arrays.

Also, functions with forwarding references as function parameter (`T&&` where `T` is a template parameter) are not expected to have the corresponding type template argument (for `T`) specified explicitly. So just drop the template argument list in the call completely. It is supposed to be deduced, otherwise the forwarding reference will not work as intended.

For example:

```
std::string arr[] = { "1", "2", "3" };
foo(arr);
```

But then the function specialization will fail to instantiate, because built-in arrays don't have members that can be referred to with the member access operator as in `a.size()`. So the function is not usable at all. (I am not sure whether you made a mistake here reducing the actual function to an example or whether you are trying to write a function accepting `std::array` yourself, in which case the other answers are giving good suggestions.)

Answer (score 5):

`std::is_array_v<std::array<T, N>>` yields `false` for any `T` and `N`. You need to create a custom type trait or simply write the function differently:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void foo(std::array<T, N> const& a)
{
    std::cout << a.size() << std::endl;
}
```

or

```
template<class T>
struct is_std_array : std::false_type {};
 
template<class T, size_t N>
struct is_std_array<std::array<T, N>> : std::true_type {};

template<class T>
constexpr bool is_std_array_v = is_std_array<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>::value;

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_std_array_v<T>, bool> = false>
void foo(T&& a)
{
    std::cout << a.size() << std::endl;
}
```

See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:tree,i:(cmakeArgs:%27%27,compilerLanguageId:c%2B%2B,customOutputFilename:%27%27,files:!((editorId:1,fileId:1,filename:merge_sort.cpp,g:%27%27,isIncluded:%270%27,isMainSource:%271%27,isOpen:%270%27,langId:%27%27)),isCMakeProject:%270%27,j:1,newFileId:2),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Tree+%231%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:6.52677579841867,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:merge_sort.cpp,fontScale:16,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:14),source:%27%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T,+size_t+N%3E%0Avoid+foo(std::array%3CT,+N%3E+const%26+a)%0A%7B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+a.size()+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate%3Cclass+T%3E%0Astruct+is_std_array+:+std::false_type+%7B%7D%3B%0A+%0Atemplate%3Cclass+T,+size_t+N%3E%0Astruct+is_std_array%3Cstd::array%3CT,+N%3E%3E+:+std::true_type+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Cclass+T%3E%0Aconstexpr+bool+is_std_array_v+%3D+is_std_array%3Cstd::remove_cvref_t%3CT%3E%3E::value%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T,+std::enable_if_t%3Cis_std_array_v%3CT%3E,+bool%3E+%3D+false%3E%0Avoid+foo2(T%26%26+a)%0A%7B%0A++std::cout+%3C%3C+a.size()+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++std::array%3Cstd::string,+3%3E+str_arr+%7B+std::string(%22asdf%22),+%22zxcv%22,+%22qwer%22+%7D%3B%0A%0A++foo(str_arr)%3B%0A++foo2(str_arr)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:merge_sort.cpp,t:%270%27)),k:48.82539923378691,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g121,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20++-O2+-Wpedantic+++%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+12.1+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:44.44639279085118,l:%274%27,m:40.06085192697768,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:16,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:59.93914807302232,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:44.64782496779445,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)